# check for multiple URIs in the same prefix

Tags: xml, xquery

Is it possible to use Xquery to check if an xml document has different URIs assigned to the same name space prefix in different scopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select `(//ns1:*, //@ns1:*)/prefix-from-QName(node-name())` to find used prefixes I think:

When run on e.g.

```
<root xmlns="http://example.com/ns1">
    <pf1:foo xmlns:pf1="http://example.com/ns1">
        <pf1:bar xmlns:pf1="http://example.com/ns2"/>
        <pf3:baz xmlns:pf3="http://example.com/ns1">
            <foobar xmlns="" xmlns:pf4="http://example.com/ns1" pf4:att1="whatever"/>
        </pf3:baz>
    </pf1:foo>
</root>
```

it returns `pf1 pf3 pf4`, use `count(distinct-values((//ns1:*, //@ns1:*)/prefix-from-QName(node-name())))` to check whether there is more than one used. Example: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5t/1

Not sure about the empty prefix, it might need some extra handling it seems as it is not included in the above result.

Comment: This only checks namespace prefixes actually used in element and attribute names; it doesn't check prefixes that are declared but unused (or used only in content, e.g. contained QNames or XPath expressions).

Comment: @MichaelKay, yes, you are right, as XQuery I think doesn't support the namespace axis I looked for nodes in a certain namespace as an example, I guess a more complete solution needs to use the functions in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#QName-functions and do some grouping of nodes by namespace and then by prefix. As for contained QNames, that might need schema-aware processing to identify content of that kind, no?